# What is the best (stable) Media Center to connect windows xp and play station 3

Tags: windows-xp, windows-media-player, ps3

I am looking for a stable service like Media Center to connect my Windows XP Home Edition and Play Station 3 to view my video files via my TV connected to ps3. Windows Media Player works unstable, sometimes I am getting error on ps3 (internal error...and so on...). Maybe someone is using a good and smart tool which transfer video from my PC to PS3. 
Any way, thank you.

Comment: This might fit better on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XBMC has a pretty good UPNP server.

Comment: It seems, it is just a powerful player. Can ps3 connect to it? Do you mean, is it possible to install it to the ps3 directly?

Comment: Yes PS3 can connect to it over a network. Your media library is exposed as a UPNP service... just like TVersity.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [ps3mediaserver](http://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver/)?  I've used it a little bit and it has worked fine for me.

Comment: I tried it yesterday. It does not work via wireless connection. :(. But it free.